# Action ML Classifier not giving expected results

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array, coreml, wwdc

I am creating an app which detect the exercises. i trained the model using create ML. i got 100% result in create ML application. But when i am integrating into the application using `Vision` framework it's always showing only one exercise. i followed the code exactly from [Build an Action Classifier with Create ML](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10043/) for creating ml and requesting `VNHumanBodyPoseObservation`. Followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/building_a_feature-rich_app_for_sports_analysis) for converting `VNHumanBodyPoseObservation` to `MLMultiArray`.

Here is the code what i do:

```
func didOutput(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
    self.extractPoses(pixelBuffer)
}
func extractPoses(_ pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
    let request = VNDetectHumanBodyPoseRequest { (request, err) in
        if err == nil {
            if let observations =
                request.results as? [VNRecognizedPointsObservation], observations.count > 0 {
                if let prediction = try? self.makePrediction(observations) {
                    print("\(prediction.label), confidence: \(prediction.confidence)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
      do {
        // Perform the body pose-detection request.
        try handler.perform([request])
      } catch {
        print("Unable to perform the request: \(error).\n")
      }
}


func makePrediction(_ observations: [VNRecognizedPointsObservation]) throws -> (label: String, confidence: Double) {
    let fitnessClassifier = try PlayerExcercise(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())

        let numAvailableFrames = observations.count
        let observationsNeeded = 60
        var multiArrayBuffer = [MLMultiArray]()

        for frameIndex in 0 ..< min(numAvailableFrames, observationsNeeded) {
            let pose = observations[frameIndex]
            do {
                let oneFrameMultiArray = try pose.keypointsMultiArray()
                multiArrayBuffer.append(oneFrameMultiArray)
            } catch {
                continue
            }
        }
        
        // If poseWindow does not have enough frames (45) yet, we need to pad 0s
        if numAvailableFrames < observationsNeeded {
            for _ in 0 ..< (observationsNeeded - numAvailableFrames) {
                do {
                    let oneFrameMultiArray = try MLMultiArray(shape: [1, 3, 18], dataType: .double)
                    try resetMultiArray(oneFrameMultiArray)
                    multiArrayBuffer.append(oneFrameMultiArray)
                } catch {
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
    let modelInput = MLMultiArray(concatenating: [MLMultiArray](multiArrayBuffer), axis: 0, dataType: .float)
//
//
let predictions = try fitnessClassifier.prediction(poses: modelInput)

return (label: predictions.label, confidence: predictions.labelProbabilities[predictions.label]!)

}

func resetMultiArray(_ predictionWindow: MLMultiArray, with value: Double = 0.0) throws {
    let pointer = try UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Double>(predictionWindow)
    pointer.initialize(repeating: value)
}
```

**I suspect the issue happening while converting VNRecognizedPointsObservation to MLMultiArray Please help me, i am trying to achieve this so hard. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your app on a simulator? Because I had the same issue that the model predicted wrong results when I ran my image classifier app on a iPhone 12 simulator. But the issue was solved when I tried to run the app on a real device. So maybe there is nothing wrong with your model or code, try running it on a real device and see if you get your intended results.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30345858)